# how to get the value of multidimensional array pass from jquery and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I send a multidimensional array from ajax.js to test1.php. But then I do not know how to retrieve the multidimensional array in my test1.php. I have found lots of examples but they did not work for me.

ajax.js

```
answers = {};
answers[0] = {};
answers[0]['question_id'] = '12';
answers[0]['answer_id'] = '32';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test1.php',
    data: {answers: answers},
    //dataType: "json",

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('success!');
    }
});
```

test1.php

```
$a=$_POST['answers'][0]['answer_id'];
echo "$a"; //display nothing, I wish to display '32' here
```

Appreciate for any helps. Thanks!

Update: I included library and Ajax.js does give me an alert 'success'. So this is not the library problem. Thanks again for any helps!

Comment: Maybe jQuery is sending it in JSON. Try using `json_decode`. Try dumping `$_POST` to be sure what you are getting.

Comment: @SebastianOsuna `json_decode()`? no. you can already get that straight from the `$_POST` no need to decode anything, what the OP needs to check is the path of the PHP file if its correct, and check the console browser for errors. and make sure that jquery is indeed in there

Comment: it is working.. have you included the library?

Comment: which library? Sorry I am really new in ajax.Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're creating objects, not arrays, just do `print_r($_POST['answers']);` and see what structure it returns

Comment: you are using jquery.so you must include the library first.

Comment: I included it in my ajax.js, but problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
answers = {};
answers[0] = {};
answers[0]['question_id'] = '12';
answers[0]['answer_id'] = '32';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test1.php',
    data: {answers: answers},
    //dataType: "json",

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('success!');
    }
});
</script>
```

`test1.php`

```
<?php
$a=$_POST['answers'][0]['answer_id'];
echo "$a hello"; //display nothing, I wish to display '32' here
```

Comment: yes I have included library and Ajax.js does give me an alert 'success'. So this is not the library problem. Thanks again for any helps!

Comment: is that request successfull?

Comment: $a is null. Nothing display in test1.php. I think it might not successful.

Comment: use developer tools and see it under netwrok tab. u will the response and request there.